# How can I generate multiple timers in WPF when elements are in a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I manage to access objects in Code Behind from Window.Resources?

[image: Generated from resources]

Follow-up:

Actually, I'm trying to generate multiple timers. How can I properly to do it in WPF if my elements are inside a DataTemplate?

[image: timers]

Comment: The "Name" is a member variable of the object specfied in XAML. Scratch that, I see you asked about resources. Usually you just reference the object by type (e.g. TextBlock) if you have more than one they use name styles i the resource definition.

Comment: in your code behind, you can just reference it by Name.  So in the code behind try 'nameLabel.Content = "TEST"'

Comment: What do you want that for? Don't use code behind in WPF. Much less if you're talking about a `DataTemplate`. What do you want those elements for?

Comment: @jonesy Wrong. Those elements are inside a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: ah yes correct you are

Comment: Honestly, the one correct answer i can give you is: You don't. If you need it, write a custom control with the logic you need and use that in your DataTemplate.

Comment: I update my question. what is proper way to do it?

Comment: @jesson What do `multiple timers` have to do with UI elements? Put that logic in a ViewModel.

Comment: What do you need to access the items by name for? Cannot it be solved with just binding?

Answer (score 1):

To find control inside template/datatemplate use FindName method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx

**EDIT:**

Or you could use class and TwoWay binding to set text or whatever you need.

```
class MyCustomTimer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string title { get; set; }
    DispatcherTimer timer { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Bind in template with TwoWay binding:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding title, Mode=TwoWay} />
```

Add class to listview:

```
this.listview.items.add(new MyCustomTimer(...));
```

And then access values in datatemplate like:

```
MyCustomTimer item0 = this.listview.Items[0] as MyCustomTimer;

item0.title = "This is text";
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can think for it. no you can't access the elements inside a a datatemplate. A [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) is just a representation /xaml view of the managed object. so if you have something which is useful to you. I recommend you to use the [Custom control](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html) and create some [TemplateParts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179105/How-to-access-Control-Template-parts-from-Code-Beh) for it. by this way you can get the [template part from the code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179105/How-to-access-Control-Template-parts-from-Code-Beh).

Other thing you can do is use the [VisualTreehelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class this will give you the parents and childs from the elements.